# How to let loop move to the next row?

Tags: c++, loops

In my code `KNN_classifier` function has to call the `Euclidean_distance` and store its retuned values in an array called `array_dist[i]`. Actually, the returned values of `Euclidean_distance` are not correct.
After revising the code several times. I think that the loops don't move to the next rows.
I have 4344 rows and 20 columns. Do I need to use transfer_index or something like that??

```
void KNN_classifier(int X_train[4344][20],
                    int Y_train[4344],
                    int array_X_set[5430][20],
                    int data_point[20])
{
    float array_dist[4344]{};
    int index_arr[4344]{};
    int myxtrain[20] = {};
    int mydatapoint[20] = {};
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 4344; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; ++j) {
            myxtrain[j] = X_train[i][j]; 
            mydatapoint[j] = array_X_set[i][j];
        }
        array_dist[i] = Euclidean_distance(myxtrain, mydatapoint);
        index_arr[i] = i;
    }

    std::cout << "print out distance colum:\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 4344; ++i)
         {
             std::cout << index_arr[i] << " : "
                       << array_dist[i] << std::endl;
         }
}
```

My main:

```
int main ()
{
// ...
    KNN_classifier(X_train, Y_train, array_X_set,data_point);
}
```

Comment: " I think that the loops don't move to the next rows." why do you think that? Your function returns nothing and prints nothing, so how do you actually know that there is something wrong? What exactly is wrong about it?

Comment: Your copies to `myxtrain`, `mydatapoint` seems unneeded, `array_dist[i] = Euclidean_distance(X_train[i], array_X_set[i]);` should be equivalent.

Comment: Is it normal that `array_X_set` has different size than `X_train`?

Comment: @Jarod42 yes this is normal

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number I didn't post the whole code to keep my post minimal

Comment: @Jarod42 so do you think I have to use some index

Comment: but the wrong results and your way to see that the results are wrong is essential, without that information we cannot help. See [mcve]

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_numberI just update my code, plz check

Comment: ok, but what do you mean with " I think that the loops don't move to the next rows." ? Does it mean the loop to pritn the results prints 4344 times the same number? Please provide a [mcve] including example input, output and expected output

Comment: Do you really need 4344 rows for a minimal example? What about 3?

Comment: My results are correct [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/37317f88df77f779).

Answer (score 0):

as a general case for a 2d array to be converted to a linear array we can use the following :

```
int index = row * width + col;
```

OR

```
int index = y * width + x;
```

where row and col are variables and width is a fixed number.